# Upgrade Webpack from 3.12 to latest

Tags: reactjs

I'm a part-time React guy and need to upgrade from React 16.13.1 to the latest (17.x). It seems I need to upgrade WebPack first. This seems harder than I hoped. My Webpack.config looks like this:

[image]

I'm unsure of the order of upgrades.

Simply trying: `npm install webpack@latest`

results in:

[image]

It seems to want babel-loader updated to the latest?

But then I do `npm upgrade -D babel-core@latest`, it says I am at latest.

Maybe that's the latest for React16?

Any guidance would be great.

Doing Webpack 3 to 4, results in errors as well. `npm install --save-dev webpack@4.0.0`

[image]

Comment: Roll back to the start, upgrade 3.12 to 4.0.0, update all the libraries that now need updating too, as well, and then you fix all the code that broke. Then you commit those changes, push your v4 branch, and then upgrade Webpack to the latest 4.x available. Upgrade all the libraries that need upgrading now too, again. And fix anything that broken. Commit _those_ changes. Then you do 5.0.0; then the latest 5.x; you don't jump the entire river, you'll drown. Cross the bridges from one island to the next until you're across.

Comment: Thanks @Mike'Pomax'Kamermans - that makes a lot of sense, So some form of npm upgrade webpack@4 ? See edit. Similar errors.

Comment: "and the libraries that need it" is pretty crucial. You can't just update webpack and call it a day, anything that web uses (web pack plugins, babel, babel plugins, etc) need updating in tandem, which is why you update webpack and all webpack associated libraries in lockstep, using small steps. The npm log is literally telling you which libraries are now in conflict due to version requirement mismatching, so just read the log (treat it like normal text: it's telling you everything you need to know) and then update the libraries it tells you have version mismatches to "just high enough" too.

Answer (score -1):

From your current webpack version to latest there were majors changes in webpack config itself and dependencies, like some got deprecated and replaced by another one. I did upgrade from v4 to v5 and the process was similar as commented, updating the packages and fixing the changes related to them, also checking the things that were updated/deleted in my webpack file.

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).